# Resize text to fit in expandable contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, sass

I have an expanding `contentEditable` which grows from 50px to a maximum of 300px, depending on the amount of text entered in the field.

**When the field reaches its maximum size of 300px, I'd like to begin shrinking the text in the `contentEditable`.** Until the text pushes the `contentEditable` to its maximum size I'd like to keep the text at its original size.

I'd like to do this with just CSS, but JavaScript solutions are welcome as well.

I can find info on how to fit text, or fit the element to the contained text, but not to implement a hybrid solution like this.

**Edit**

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="display:flex;">
  <div contenteditable="true" style="font-size: 2rem; margin: 10px; background: #ddd; border: 3px solid #ccc; min-width:50px; width:auto; max-width:300px; white-space: nowrap; text-align:center; overflow:hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please come up what you have tried so far.

Comment: I see no non-hacky way to go about this. The only way I see is measuring the size of the `contentEditable` on each keystroke and then updating the CSS for the element dynamically. There's plenty of other things I'd try if the `contentEditable` itself didn't grow, but since it does, I'm not sure what better method there is. I'm sure there must be something better.

Comment: Can you provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the relevant code and CSS so that we can see what's you have done so far?

Comment: @Girish thanks for your reply. I've updated my question to include a JSFiddle with an example of what I'm working with.

Comment: what will happen when a user write a lot of text and the `font-size` get shrinked to something like 6px ? user won't be able to read what he's typing

Comment: @CalvinNunes There's a maximum field length in place, and the field is a title field and not meant to be very long. This is acceptable behavior for my purpose, if I could only shrink the text to begin with.

Comment: so, use an `oninput` listener in the div, check it's width size, if > 300, change the div `font-size` to something smaller than the previous font-size.

Comment: The width doesn't go above 300 no matter what. This leaves me with the option of blindly guessing at what size to make the text to fit based on the number of characters. This is only a reliable method if I use a monospace font, and even then it's very hacky. I'm looking for a more proper text fitting solution.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you need to *shrink the text*, instead you can overflow the text by removing these css properties `white-space: nowrap; text-align:center; overflow:hidden;`.

please have a look at the the below working snippet, to see what i mean, hope it helps :)

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="display:flex;">
  <div contenteditable="true" style="font-size: 2rem; margin: 10px; background: #ddd; border: 3px solid #ccc; min-width:50px; width:auto; max-width:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @girish, but I need it to shrink. The `overflow: hidden` is there for a good reason.